# Ruby Regexp ( Match string inside brackets )

Tags: regex, logging, apache2, fluentd

Does any one know how to match a string not in brackets [^...]
ex: i want to match everything until the last "space and [" together

```
This is my regex: (?<cookie>[^[( \[)]]*)
This is my string: country=US; lngCode=en; ga_cid=a*d%5d]7b7[6-4369-ad62-9 [
This is my result: country=US;
This is what i would like to have: country=US; lngCode=en; ga_cid=a*d%5d]7b7[6-4369-ad62-9
```

My regex its matching the first space not the space and the [ together

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/^(?<cookie>.*) \[$/`. It will match and capture everything from the beginning of a line up to the final "space + literal '['" at the end of this string.

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/c7OATKe151).